# data from vtk to python

Tags: python, vtk

So this should be a fast question to answer. I am parsing a *vtk file with a python script.

In this line I obtain a certain field like temperature:

```
field = vtk_to_numpy(data.GetPointData().GetArray("Temperature"))
```

straight after i want to obtain another field like nodal conductivity:

```
kappa = vtk_to_numpy(data.GetPointData().GetArray("Heat.conductivity"))
```

everything works ok for the temperature field, but for the conductivity field i get the following message:

```
kappa = vtk_to_numpy(data.GetPointData().GetArray("Heat.conductivity"))
  File "~anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vtk/util/numpy_support.py", line 215, in vtk_to_numpy
    typ = vtk_array.GetDataType()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetDataType'
```

Can someone explain why it works for the temperature field, and not for the conductivity?

Comment: The fact that it's saying a `NoneType` is being operated on makes me think that it's exiting out of one of the Get functions early. Are you sure "Heat.conductivity" is the right name of the field? I would check with `GetNumberOfArrays()` and `GetArrayName` to make sure the fields you expect to see actually exist.

Comment: The field Heat.conductivity is included in the *.vtk file. is there any way to say "get fields number one and two"????? @ahota

Comment: Yes, there's also a `GetArray` signature that takes an integer index: https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkFieldData.html#a888a6492210426d4ba4d358b87ab198f. It says it's not recommended (they prefer the polymorphic version), but it's still worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

So after surfing on the web I found he next flag I was supposed to turn on while reading the *.vtk file,

```
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
```

Now everything works as planned.